# How select all rows in table rather than visible rows in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in HTML with pagination. I need to convert the table to csv. The following code used to get all visible rows in the current page of the table.

```
$(el).find('tr').each(function() {
    var tmpRow = [];
    $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none')
            tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData($(this).html());
    });
    row2CSV(tmpRow);
});
```

So, how can I select all rows in the table no matter pagination or not rather than select current visible rows. Please help me ! Thank you!

Comment: Um, Remove the visible check!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(el).find('tr').each(function() {
                var tmpRow = [];
                $(this).find('td').each(function() {
                        tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData($(this).html());
                });
                row2CSV(tmpRow);
            });
```

Removed **:visible** check and following condition

> $(this).css('display') != 'none'